# консольная команда чтобы ограничить права пользователя чтобы он не мог не чего создать на рабочем столе

Tags: windows-10

ребят как ограничить нового пользователя через консоль что бы он не мог не чего создавать на рабочем столе

Comment: Если вы администратор ПК, а новая учетка пользовательская, думаю поможет ограничение прав на запись к папке C:\Users\учетка\Desktop, если прям очень хочется в консоли - есть утилита icacls, погуглите как ее применять сами